# How to set parameters for Gibbs sampling

Tags: r, parameters, text-mining, lda, topic-modeling

I'm performing LDA topic modeling on my dataset of tweets collected from several twitter accounts which consists of 9582 documents and 4144 terms after pre-processing. In order to run the LDA function, I have to define the parameter values that control how many Gibbs sampling draws are made when running the model.

```
fitted_many <- lapply(sequ, function(k) LDA(dtmTopicModeling, k = k,
method = "Gibbs",control = list(burnin = burnin, iter = iter, keep = keep) ))
```

How do I define the values of **burnin**, **iter** and **keep** for the above function?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the anonymous function for `lapply` here, since all you're doing is passing the `k` value along to `LDA`. Instead, you want something like:

```
fitted_many <- lapply(sequ,
                      LDA,
                      x = dtmTopicModeling,
                      method = "Gibbs",
                      control = list(burnin = burnin_value,
                                     iter = iter_value,
                                     keep = keep_value))
```

As Oriol mentions, the `...` arguments in `lapply` will be passed to the referenced function. By referencing `LDA` directly in `lapply`, you just have to make sure to name the `x` argument, since the `k` value is the second argument for `LDA`.

On the other hand, if you need different values of `burnin`, `iter`, and `keep` for each `k` value, then you would need to pass multiple varying arguments. There are several ways to do that, though I think `purrr::pmap` is the most direct.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `lapply` is `lapply(X, FUN, ...)`. The three dots refer to the optional arguments to FUN. So you should be able to provide those arguments separated by commas after the function.